# Union returning different outputs with limit postgresql

Tags: mysql, postgresql, union

I have to fetch 12 questions from my question set based on the difficulty level. Following is the query I have written.

```
(SELECT q.question_text, q.option_a, q.option_b, q.option_c, q.option_d,
        q.correct_answer, q.image_link, q.question_type
        FROM questions_bank q
        JOIN sports_type st ON st.id = q.sports_type_id
        JOIN difficulty_level dl ON dl.id = q.difficulty_level_id
        WHERE st.game_type = LOWER('cricket') AND dl.value = 'E'
        ORDER BY random()
        LIMIT 7) 
UNION 
(SELECT q.question_text, q.option_a, q.option_b, q.option_c, q.option_d,
        q.correct_answer, q.image_link, q.question_type
        FROM questions_bank q
        JOIN sports_type st ON st.id = q.sports_type_id
        JOIN difficulty_level dl ON dl.id = q.difficulty_level_id
        WHERE st.game_type = LOWER('cricket') AND dl.value = 'M'
        ORDER BY random()
        LIMIT 4)
UNION 
(SELECT q.question_text, q.option_a, q.option_b, q.option_c, q.option_d, 
        q.correct_answer, q.image_link, q.question_type
        FROM questions_bank q
        JOIN sports_type st ON st.id = q.sports_type_id
        JOIN difficulty_level dl ON dl.id = q.difficulty_level_id
        WHERE st.game_type = LOWER('cricket') AND dl.value = 'H'
        ORDER BY random()
        LIMIT 1);
```

The issue is that whenever I run this query, each time it gives me a different number of results instead of the static 12. Sometimes I get 12, sometimes 10, sometimes 15. I expect 12 rows in output, not less, not more.

What is wrong in this query?

Comment: Your query should return max 12 rows not more. To get exactly 12 use [`union all`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-select.html#SQL-UNION)

Comment: FYI , `UNION` removes duplicates and `UNION ALL` doesn't.Try to avoid extraneous tags

Comment: It's may be possible that query return less than 12 rows but not possible to return more than 12.Are you sure it's return 15 rows some time?

Comment: I don't want duplicates, hence using UNION. And yes, it sometimes returns more than 12 rows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be reduced to a single select by using a window function:

```
select *
from (
    select
        row_number() over (partition by dl.value order by random()) as rn,
        dl.value,
        q.question_text, q.option_a, q.option_b, q.option_c, q.option_d,
        q.correct_answer, q.image_link, q.question_type
    from
        questions_bank q
        inner join
        sports_type st on st.id = q.sports_type_id
        inner join
        difficulty_level dl on dl.id = q.difficulty_level_id
    where st.game_type = lower('cricket') and dl.value in ('E','M','H')
) s
where 
    value = 'E' and rn <= 7 or
    value = 'M' and rn <= 4 or
    value = 'H' and rn = 1
```

Comment: @wingedpanther I have been ninja'd by someone else today so my revenge was on you! :))

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works perfectly. :)

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto, I need your help again. I need to add a condition to this query. So, if dl.value='E' then 50% of the easy questions should be from a category. (need to join with another table questions_category, INNER JOIN question_category qc ON qc.id = q.question_category_id). how shall I add a inner join here?

Comment: @AnkitaGupta Open another question referring to this one for context.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto refer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42160359/postgresql-condition-on-where-clause-with-join)